# adding events for a component that is not rendered Extjs 4?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a form and a tabpanel The user is supposed to enter some information in the form and click a submit button at the end. I have a controller that controls that button click event and fires various application level events depending upon the input. I catch those events in controllers for all the tabs and do individual processing. What happens is that as not all the tabs are rendered in the beginning and therefore, only the first tab displays the output and others give error. I would like to know if there is a way that i can catch the event in a way that it first waits for the components to get rendered and then does the processing.

Thanks.

Comment: what error does other tabs give? If their is dependency why you are trying to defer other tabs from rendering? What kind of output you are  expecting in your tabs?

Comment: Well I am not deferring the rendering myself. But as it appears, other tabs do not render as long as i don't click on them. Is there a way to render all of them at application start up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please have a look at **deferredRender : Boolean** config for tabpanel.
>
> **True by default** to defer the rendering of child items to the browsers DOM until a tab is activated. False will render all contained items as soon as the layout is rendered. If there is a significant amount of content or a lot of heavy controls being rendered into panels that are not displayed by default, setting this to true might improve performance.

Comment: Thank you very much this worked for now. I might have to do something different because there is so much on the tabs that need not be rendered at start but for now its a good feeling to have accomplished what i wanted. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

How about yor inital handler queues some sort of `pendingJob` object for those tabs `!rendered` and then on the `afterrender` or `show` event you check that, process it and clear it? I do something similar with a cards layout and it works very well.

Comment: Yes That is exactly what i need. What I was thinking to do is creating global boolean variables and use them to see what the user has input. But it didn't feel the right way. Do you think that is a good idean? I was hoping that there would be the possibility to fire an event and catch it later or something, or may be catch it in the afterrender or force the rendering of objects to get some jobs done. But I think you have a good point and I should try that. Or something in that direction. Thanks

Comment: Global variables are not good practice. But it's not the devil. You don't have to break your MVC logic. 1. Fire events that input changed. 2. The interested controllers listen to the event and when fired, they check if visible/rendered/ready. If yes, update. If not, mark as dirty or something, for when ready. When will they be ready? I use `show` event and/or `afterrender`.

Comment: yes I will use afterrender as well. Thanks a lot i will need to do something like this eventually but for now i will set the deferrender to false and render all tabs at the app startup. For improving the performance i will use this option once i know the ins and outs of the MVC better. Thanks again for your nice suggestion